# partition function including multiplicities.

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

It could be ambiguous question.

Is there a notion for a partition function including "multiplicities"?

For example, the above "multiplicities" means that

$$3=1+1+1={\color{red}{1+2}}={\color{red}{2+1}}$$

counting $1+2$ and $2+1$ are distinguished.

If anyone knows the relevant concepts, can you give me a reference or a textbook?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When order matters, the term used is Compositions rather than Partitions. As a first step you could check out the Wikipedia entry for these.